# chatter question and answer in salesforce1

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, chatter-answers

I have a visual force page which displays the Q&A tab in salesforce1 app. Below is the screenshot of my page:

When I type something like a string "test", it displays some results in suggested search results. When I click on some result, it is redirecting to a page. Here is the screenshot of the redirecting page:

[image: When I typed "test"]

[image: Error page]
I am not getting why is this error coming. Any help or work around on this is appreciable.